# Swift Wrapped Functions Support

Tags: swift, function

I am trying to retrieve the value from the function below.

I simply want to be able to call the function using:

```swift
steps = getStepCountForDayXDaysAgo(4)

// Function to query Step Count for X days ago
func getStepCountForDayXDaysAgo(_ daysAgo: Int, completion: @escaping (Double?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -daysAgo, to: calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()))!
    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictEndDate)
    
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { (query, result, error) in
        guard let result = result, error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        
        let steps = result.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count())
        completion(steps, nil)
    }
    
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

However Xcode keeps prompting me to use something along the lines of the following:

```swift
getStepCountForDayXDaysAgo(2) { (stepCount, error) in
if let stepCount = stepCount {
    // Use the step count value here
    print("Step count: \(stepCount)")
} else {
    // Handle the error here
    print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
}}
```

I really don't want to mess around with the error statement. I want either the step count or a 0 if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the completion handler* since you are dealing with asynchronous code but you can get rid of the error and optional result.

First change the signature of the function so that the completion handler expects a `Double` as input only

```
func getStepCountForDayXDaysAgo(_ daysAgo: Int, completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void)
```

Then change the content of the query closure to match the completion handler

```
guard let result = result, error == nil else {
    completion(0)
    return
}

let steps = result.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count()) ?? 0
completion(steps)
```

Then you can call the method like this

```
var steps = 0.0
getStepCountForDayXDaysAgo(4) { steps = $0 }
```

** You could perhaps also use a solution using async/await*